# Looping checkbox not all values adding to database

Tags: django

I have the following function, what it should do it loop the values submitted in a checkbox called groups, then submit each value to the database. However it appears to only add one value to the database. Is there anything wrong?

**groups = 1,3,3,4**

**function UPDATED**

```
def add_batch(request):
    # If we had a POST then get the request post values.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BatchForm(request.POST)
        # Check we have valid data before saving trying to save.
        if form.is_valid():
            # Clean all data and add to var data.
            data = form.cleaned_data
            groups = data['groups'].split(",")
            for item in groups:
                batch = Batch(content=data['message'],
                              group=Group.objects.get(pk=item),
                              user=request.user
                              )
                batch.save()
    return redirect(batch.get_send_conformation_page())
```

**Post vars:**

```
groups  1, 3, 4
```

**Form:**

```
<form action="{% url 'add_batch' %}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     {% for item in groups %}
         <label class="groups">
            <input type="checkbox" name="groups" value="{{ item.id }}" /> {{item.name}}<br />
         </label>

     {% endfor %}
</form>
```

**forms.py**

```
class BatchForm(forms.Form):

    groups = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Please don't use `for item range(len(groups))`. `for item in groups` is clearer, then `item` is the actual object you need.

Comment: Could you post your Django form as well?

Comment: @Daniel for in groups give me list indices must be integers, not unicode

Comment: You ignored the second part of my comment. `item` is now the actual element in the list, so you would just do `Group.objects.get(pk=item)`.

Comment: @Daniel thanks I see, my bad. Still have my original issue tho, only adding one of the items even when a list of 1,2,3 etc is posted

Comment: It wasn't supposed to be an answer to your question, which is why I posted it as a comment. Still, I agree with Vincent that we need to see the code of your form.

Comment: @Daniel it was a good point, no offense. I have updated the question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have multiple checkboxes on a page and each has the name `groups`. This is perfectly OK.

When you submit a form like this, the params may look like this:

```
?groups=1&groups=3&groups=4
```

Your form definition, on the other hand, is defining groups as a `CharField`. It will be populated with with a value retrieved from `request.GET['groups']` which will only retrieve one of the above values.

I think you would be better off if you defined `groups` as:

```
CHOICES = (
(0, '1'),
(1, '2'),
(2, '3'),
)

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    groups = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            choices=CHOICES, 
            label="Groups", 
            required=False)
```

Comment: can CHOICES in this situation come from a query?

Comment: @Spike for that use forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField, which takes a queryset.